# What does it mean to find dimensions of a figure in calculus?

Tags: calculus

I came across many optimization problems in calculus asking to find dimensions of a figure that minimize or maximize something.
For example, the dimensions of a rectangle or cylinder and the answers to those problems show the lengths of sides or radius and they don't say something like "the dimensions are ….." Am I understanding problems wrong?

Example) A cylindrical can is to be made to hold 1L of oil. Find the dimensions that will minimize the cost of the metal to manufacture the can.

I just edited the question.

Comment: This question is too vague. Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: Can you give an example that explains your question?  For example if the largest rectangle inside a circle of radius $1$ is a square with sides $\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Dimensions just means the measurements that specify some geometric figure.  The dimensions of a square might be 7 by 7.  The dimensions of a cylinder might be radius = 5, length = 72.  Or whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of calculus problems involving optimization 
 the dimension of an object are those lengths which completely describe the object.

For example a square  is described by its side length, and a rectangle is described by the length and the width while a triangle is described either by the side lengths or by the base and height and so forth, depending on the question.

For a cube the length of one side and for a cylinder the radius of the base and the height describe the object.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification!

Comment: Thanks for attention and understanding.